# Use Traefik as two different frontends to two different load balancers within the one Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, traefik

I currently have Traefik deployed to Azure Service Fabric that have placement constraint to the public facing DMZ nodes or scaleset and therefore The Traefik frontend forwards requests from the DMZ load-balancer IP to the ASF applications defined as back-ends. This is working well.

I wish to have Traefik ALSO have a frontend on the private scale-set /load-balancer so that requests are forwarded, again to backend applications without needing to hop through the DMZ load-balancer.

Is this possible?

Does this mean deploying the single Traefik app to both private and public ASF nodes/scale-sets?

If one deployment, then how do you define config so one entrypoint is used for one incoming (load-balancer)  IP/host list and other entrypoint is handling another incoming (load-balancer) IP/host list

OR deploying Traefik twice as separate apps to each ASF scale-set, each having their own configuration. If twice, can ASF integrate with two instances of Traefik?

Is there any example out there of this working?

I forked my existing Traefik app repo, adjusted to deploy to private Azure Service Fabric nodes with a different App/Type name but there are unexpected startup errors - too generic to tell what the issue is, perhaps two Traefik apps deployed to the same Service Fabric is not supported - only one app handling all the entrypoints? Meaning I need to deploy Traefik to all nodes/scale-sets to handle requests to both load-balancers?